# Why is the compiler only compiling the first two sections of my code?

Tags: java

Ok, so I am making a computer program game that asks for the name of the user and their desired winning number. Then, I launched into the code.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; //For user input
public class Guts 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
//Variable declarations
String userName = "";
int winningNumber;
boolean done = false;

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.println("Please type your name.");
userName = keyboard.next();

System.out.println("Welcome " + userName + ", to a game of Guts!");


 while (!done){

  System.out.println("Enter the winning number (20-50):");
  winningNumber = keyboard.nextInt(); 
  if (winningNumber >= 20 && winningNumber <=50)
  {
     System.out.println("Awesome! Great number!");
     done = true;
     }
  else 
  {
     System.out.println("This number is incorrect. Please enter a number between 20 and 50.");

  }

}


}



boolean humanTurn = true; 
boolean computerTurn = true;
int dice;
int humanTurnScore, computerTurnScore;  
int humanTotalScore = 0;
int computerTotalScore = 0; 


public void roll()  
    {  
    dice = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;                   
    }    

public int humanTurnScore()  
    {  
        {  
            humanTurnScore = dice + humanTurnScore;
            System.out.println("You rolled:" + dice);
            System.out.println("Your turn score is " + humanTurnScore + ".");
            } return humanTurnScore;  
        } 
public void humanTurnZero()
{
   humanTurnScore = 0;
} 

 public int computerTurnScore()  
    {  
        {  
            computerTurnScore = dice + computerTurnScore;  
            System.out.println("Computer has scored: " + computerTurnScore + " in its turn.");
            } return computerTurnScore;
      }     
 public void computerTurnZero()
    {
       computerTurnScore = 0;
    } 

public Guts()  
{  
    humanGame();  
    if(!humanTurn)  
    {  
        computerTurn();  
    }  
}  
public int humanGame()
   {             
    System.out.println("To start the game please press 's'.");  
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);  
    String start = key.nextLine();  
    if(!start.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) 
    {
           System.out.println("Make sure you are pressing 's'.");
           humanGame();
    }

    if(start.equalsIgnoreCase("s"))
       {                          
                    System.out.println("You pressed 's'.");  
                    System.out.println("Lets start.");           


        do{  
            roll();    


            if(dice == 1)  
            {  
                System.out.println("You got 1 and you lost your turn.");
                System.out.println("Computer's total score is: " + computerTotalScore);
                humanTurnZero();            
                computerTurn();  

            }  
            else if(dice != 1) 
            {

                humanTotalScore += dice;  
                   if(humanTotalScore >= 50)    
                   {  
                       System.out.println("You rolled: " + dice);
                       System.out.println("Your total score is: " + humanTotalScore);
                       System.out.println("Congratulations, you win!");  
                       System.exit(0);  
                   } 
                humanTurnScore();  
                System.out.println("Your total score is: " + humanTotalScore);  
                System.out.println("Computer's total score is: " + computerTotalScore);
                System.out.println("You can hold or roll again.");  
                System.out.println("To roll again press 'r' or 'h' to hold.");  
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  
                String choice = keyboard.nextLine();  

                if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))                                  
                    {    
                      System.out.println("Lets roll again.");   
                      roll();           

                            if(!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
                               {
                                   System.out.println("You didn't press 'r'. To make sure the program is running correctly please press 'r' to roll or 'h' to hold.");
                                   humanGame();
                               }
                   }

                if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("h"))  
                    {                         
                    System.out.println("Your total score is: " + humanTotalScore);
                    humanTurnZero();  
                    computerTurn();  
                    }     

               }  

       }while(humanTurn);     

    }return dice;  
}  
public int computerTurn()  
{  
    System.out.println("Now it's computer turn.");  

do {  
    roll();  

    if(dice != 1)  
    {  
        computerTotalScore += dice; 
           if(computerTotalScore >=50)  
               {  
                   System.out.println("Computer rolled: " + dice);
                   System.out.println("Computer's total score is: " + computerTotalScore);
                   System.out.println("Game Over! the computer wins");  
                   System.exit(0);  
               }   
        System.out.println("Computer rolled: " + dice);
        System.out.println("Computer's total score is: " + computerTotalScore);
        System.out.println("Your total score is: " + humanTotalScore);
        computerTurnScore();  
        roll();  
    }  

      if(dice == 1)   
    {  
        System.out.println("Computer rolled a 1, it's turn is over.");  
        computerTurnZero();  
        humanGame();  
    }  


}while (computerTurn);  
return dice;  


}
}
```

I don't understand why the compiler won't do anything past the winning number while loop.

How can I fix the code so the whole thing will be read and not just the first part?

Comment: how do you know its not compiling rest of the part ?

Comment: AFAIK, you have 2  `while`'s . Which one you are talking about ?

Comment: add more details about you test case, where is the first and second section of code?

Comment: Your code is working perfectly fine here. So as already asked, add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, JVM comes to the main method as the first step and execute what you have mentioned there. Depending on your code you have inside the main method JVM can't come out of the while loop until you input a number between 20 and 50. If your input matches with the given credentials JVM will comes out of the loop and ends the program as JVM has nothing to do after that.
If you need to execute the other part of the program (as you have mentioned here) then you have to make an object of your class.Then the JVM will go to the constructor and do the stuff.

> Right after the while loop:

```
while (!done) {

            System.out.println("Enter the winning number (20-50):");
            winningNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (winningNumber >= 20 && winningNumber <= 50) {
                System.out.println("Awesome! Great number!");
                done = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("This number is incorrect. Please enter a number between 20 and 50.");

            }

        }
         Guts g = new Guts();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! im a total beginner and everyone in my class has been struggling with this so much.